# How can we strip punctuation at the start of a string using Python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, strip

I want to strip all kinds of punctuation at the start of the string using Python. My **list** contains strings and some of them starting with some kind of punctuation. And how can I strip all type of punctuation from the strings?

For example: If my word is like `,,gets`, I want to strip `,,` from the word, and I want `gets` as the result. Also, I want to strip away **spaces** as well as **numbers** from the **list**. I have tried with the following code but it is not producing the correct result.

If 'a' is a list containing some words:

```
for i in range (0,len(a)):
      a[i]=a[i].lstrip().rstrip()
      print a[i]
```

Comment: `str.*strip()` doesn't magically know what you want to strip, if you want to strip something other than the default.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters
>   removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of
>   characters to be removed.

Passing [`string.punctuation`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) will remove all leading and trailing punctuation chars:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

>>> l = [',,gets', 'gets,,', ',,gets,,']
>>> for item in l:
...     print item.strip(string.punctuation)
... 
gets
gets
gets
```

Or, `lstrip()` if you need only leading characters removed, `rstip()` - for trailing characters.

Hope that helps.

Comment: how can i strip spaces in a list

Comment: @user3254544 you can either add space to the "list" of chars to remove: `item.strip(string.punctuation + ' ')`, or call `strip()` afterwards `item.strip(string.punctuation).strip()`.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the characters you want to remove in `lstrip` and `rstrip`

```
'..foo..'.lstrip('.').rstrip('.') == 'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

[`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) when used without parameters strips only spaces. If you want to strip any other character, you need to pass it as a parameter to strip function. In your case you should be doing

```
a[i]=a[i].strip(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove punctuation, spaces, numbers from the beginning of each string in a list of strings:

```
import string

chars = string.punctuation + string.whitespace + string.digits    
a[:] = [s.lstrip(chars) for s in a]
```

Note: it doesn't take into account non-ascii punctuation, whitespace, or digits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove it only from the begining, try this:

```
    import re
    s='"gets'
    re.sub(r'("|,,)(.*)',r'\2',s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove all punctuation regardless of where it occurs in a list containing strings (which may contain multiple words), this should work:

```
test1 = ",,gets"
test2 = ",,gets,,"
test3 = ",,this is a sentence and it has commas, and many other punctuations!!"
test4 = [" ", "junk1", ",,gets", "simple", 90234, "234"]
test5 = "word1 word2 word3 word4 902344"

import string

remove_l = string.punctuation + " " + "1234567890"

for t in [test1, test2, test3, test4, test5]:
    if isinstance(t, str):
        print " ".join([x.strip(remove_l) for x in t.split()])
    else:
        print [x.strip(remove_l) for x in t \
               if isinstance(x, str) and len(x.strip(remove_l))]
```

Comment: `test3 = ",,this is a sentence and it has commas, and many other :-) punctuations!!"`      is like this the output should bee **, this is a sentence and it has commas , and many other :-) puntuations !!**

Answer (score 0):

```
for each_string in list:
    each_string.lstrip(',./";:') #you can put all kinds of characters that you want to ignore.
```